# Why don't my CSS variables work?

Tags: css

I was working with CSS variables for the first time and I can't get it to work. I implemented it on Chrome and triple checked my code.

```
@default: red;
#myDiv {
color: @default;
}
<div id="myDiv">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "CSS variable." Are you using a library like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)? If so, tell us.

Comment: Are you styling in Flex?

Comment: No. I didn't know you had to use a library to get this to work... I thought it was native to CSS.

Comment: What are things like "@import" called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately css doesn't natively support variables but there are libraries out there that enhance css syntax to allow you to use variables and the like. The most popular ones being Less and Sass which Matt Bell mentioned.

Basically what they do is parse the file you write, and output one where all the css variables and functions you use are compiled into a valid CSS file which you can include/use in your webpage.

http://sass-lang.com/
http://lesscss.org/

The official W3C CSS specifications:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/

**EDIT:**

Since originally answering this years ago things have changed. CSS variables are now part of the specification

For documentation / explanation check out the [excellent MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

For current/up-to-date support and statistics [check out caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables).

Comment: Since this question was answered, things changed. For support (at time of writing it is limited) check http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables For more documentation about CSS variables I would suggest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables